# paper.text() with Raphael JS and IE8 missing pixels

Tags: javascript, text, svg, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I am rendering a schema with Raphael JS. It works fine, but at some point I have many of my legends that look like it's missing a line of pixel at the bottom of the text. Like if there was a white rectangle hiding the bottom of my text. So it is still readable but ugly and not confonfortable. 
This problem occurs only on IE (i've tested only on 8), it does not appear on chrome or Firefox.
I thought I put 1 element over another but I didn't so i don't have any idea how to fix this. It doesn't occur on all my legends but i haven't been able to find out why.

Comment: You really need to post the example on a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: i have done a lot of test and it seems IE8 can't handle the generation properly. For the JS fiddle, the problem is that the code is complex and long, the graphical genration is the end of it...